# MSE of Kernel Density Estimator

Tags: r, self-study, distributions, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

Erlang Kernel is used for density estimation. By using this estimates are pretty close to the real density on graph on the other side MSE is very large. But Author of Erlang Kernel stated that it will close to *0.000266937*. Following code is used for this purpose. Please provide help how to calculate **"Mean Square Error"**.

```
n<-200
k=400
y<-rexp(n,1)

 h<-0.79 * IQR(y) * length(y) ^ (-1/5)
 x <- seq(min(y) + 0.05, max(y), length =k)
  KErlang <- matrix(rep(0, k * n), ncol = k)
 fhat <- rep(0, k)
###########erlang###########
for(j in 1:k) {
for(i in 1:n) {
KErlang[i, j] <-(1/gamma(1+(1/h)))*((1/x[j])*(1+(1/h)))^((h+1)/h)*y[i]^(1/h)*exp(-y[i]/x[j]*(1+(1/h)))
#KErlang[i, j] <-((y[i]^(x[j]/h))*exp(-(y[i]/h))/(h^((x[j]/h)+1))*factorial(x[j]/h))
}
fhat[j] <- 1/n * (sum( KErlang[, j]))
}
d1<-density(y,bw=h)
plot(x,fhat, type = "s", ylab = "Density Function", lty = 1, xlab = "Time")
lines(d1,type="p",col="red")
legend("topright", c("Real Density", "Density by Erlang Kernel"),
       col=c("red", "black"), lty=c(1,2))
A<-matrix(nrow=n, ncol=3)
for(i in 1:n){
A[i,1]<-y[i]
A[i,2]<-fhat[i]
A[i,3]<-(fhat[i]-y[i])^2
}
(sum(A[,3]))/n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a homework/self-study problem.

Your calculations (and the plots) are way off. In order to calculate the MSE you need to compare the estimated density function with the true density function and NOT with the random sample you drawn from the true distribution.

I.e. calulate:

`ftrue<-sapply(x,function(x) dexp(x,1)) #true density over the x-grid
mean((ftrue-fhat)^2) #mse of fhat w.r.t. the true density`

This will bring you to a value close to the targeted one (but obviously depends on the random.seed).

Comment: Thanks a lot @BloXX for corrections it performs very good.

Comment: can you please vote up my question?